# How to see deleted comments

Tags: support, feature-request, comments

I can understand if the poster deleted his comment

But if a moderator deletes a comment should we not be able to see it, if we want to

Divrai hoil Shel talmidai chachomim tzrichim limud

Even if we do not have talmidai chachomim now so we do not need to learn, but we should at least have the possibility to (I personally learn a lot from the comments)

Comment: My comments seem to be deleted daily. No reason is ever given.  This is the least one would expect.

Comment: @newcomer, think of comments as more like spoken words and less like permanent documents.

Answer (score 7):

[According to a a Stack Exchange employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187281/266359), there is no way for non-moderators to view deleted comments, [nor will Stack Exchange implement such a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225189/266359). Sorry.

As a piece of device from Shog's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187281/266359):

> For most intents and purposes, deleted comments are *gone* - you should
>   try your best to put anything of value into an actual answer. As you
>   note, you *can* view your own deleted answers, as well as their revision
>   histories and such - if you need or want that functionality, use
>   answers rather than comments.

Comment: I went looking for a canonical post, but remember that [comments are second class citizens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=comments+second+class+citizen) on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only thing we can do is ask the mediators that instead of deleting them they will transfer them into a chat

As the Honorable @IsaacMoses sais in a comment on the question, it is like "spoken word" (chat). So it can not be taken back

Comment: I aggree i it was technically possible to make the comment automatically part of the chat it was good. I understand that on the front of question it is esthetically good to minimize or skip comments. but if a comment has a logical context and is part of a normal discussion, to delete it may be an hefsed.

Comment: @kouty Even if losing a specific comment is a Hefsed, having a functioning site with standardized enforceable rules and policies is a Revach.

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand, as devarim shebeal pe nifsadim

Comment: Is there no way for a moderator to mark a question as "locked"? Like, the duplicates are. That could be our own little "deleted". Add "[DELETED]" and then lock it